# Would a Publications section on Careers be beneficial?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I just went to update my Careers profile with a patent, and noticed that there's no good place to put it.

Would there be any benefit in adding a 'Publications' section for things like patents and journal contributions?

Comment: No. (because I don't have any publications and I don't want you to make me look bad ;)