# Where to put my Publications (papers) on Dev Story?

Tags: discussion, support, developer-story

There is [no Publications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290267/would-a-publications-section-on-careers-be-beneficial) section in Developer Story. However I want to list my papers. Where do I do that *at the current time*?

Comment: I am using the 'Milestone' for this, with the description 'Publication'